# Trigger play on video when two divs match up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have created a way to scroll through `divs`, one has a menu and the others have divs with blanks but one has a video.

At the top of the page is a navigation menu that contains "next", "previous", "reload" and "start".
Those commands are warped in functions,

`$("#next-item").on("click", function(){`,

The page looks like this:

```
<div class="webcam-left">
  <div class="bottom-panel">
    <div class="center" id="content">
      <div class="bottom-panel-post internal start"></div>
      <div class="bottom-panel-post internal video-post"><video src="https://ia800606.us.archive.org/12/items/ACTV_News_open/ACTV_News_open.mp4"></video></div>
      <div class="bottom-panel-post internal"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="nav-right nav-main">
  <div class="rundown-panel">rundown</div>
    <div class="rundown-items">
       <div class="irl-today first"><div class="current">Welcome</div></div>
       <div class="irl-today override">Category name</div>
       <div class="irl-today">the end</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is when scrolling down the list, how do you trigger play on a video when a video is shown?

When scrolling down, I added classes to the divs that contain a video.

The left side has `.override` and the video side has `.video-post`.

I tried doing `if hasClass()` but it plays on the first click:

```
if ( $('.rundown-items').is('.override') ) {
if ($( '.bottom-panel-post' ).has('video')) {
  $('video').trigger('play');
};
};
```

Working code - https://jsfiddle.net/openbayou/paonbxcL/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, the problem was that it was looking for a class across all items and not each one individually so I added an `.each` function to look for a class on each individual div.

```
$(".slider-slide-wrap").each(function (i) {
  var posLeft = $(this).position().left
  var w = $(this).width();

  // add shown class on a div
  if (scrollLeft >= posLeft && scrollLeft < posLeft + w) {
    $(this).addClass('shown').siblings().removeClass('shown');
  }

  // if .shown has .play-video, trigger play
  if ($('.shown').is(".play-video")) {
    $('video').trigger('play');
  };
});
```